# Fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree - but it is

Tags: git, zsh, githooks

I'm actively developing working on a repo and want to add a github pre-commit hook - my first.

When I cd into the `/.git` directory I get the error `fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree`

I have tried:

1. Checking out the branch again
2. Running `git init` again
3. Setting the `GIT_WORK_TREE` env var (and `echo $GIT_WORK_TREE` to ensure it's set)
4. running `git --work-tree=. checkout branch` and `git --work-tree=${PWD} checkout branch`
5. `rm -rf` and cloning again

Any suggestions?
I am using zsh on MacOS Monterey btw and I am also using Sourcetree to manage the repo sometimes.

Thank you

Comment: The `.git` subdirectory contains the repository. The work tree is in its parent directory. You are supposed to not do anything inside the `.git` directory (except for editing a couple of configuration files but that is not a daily activity).

Comment: Thats for the instant response. Yes I want to work on the pre-commit hook in the `.git` directory

Comment: The pre-commit hook in local .git won't end up on GitHub

Comment: Yes have to move it to main repo...

Answer (score 0):

So i just ignored the error and moved `/.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample` to
`/.git/hooks/pre-commit` and added an echo line (`echo "Running git pre-commit"`) to see if it runs when it commits... it does. Seems like this is resolved.